# Some doubts on singularity of the complex function $f(z) = 1/ \sin (1/z)$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{ \sin (1/z)}$$

has a non isolated singularity at $z =0$. Since by definition of isolated singularity, every nbd of $0$, $S_{1/n}$ , $\exists $ $\frac{1}{n \pi}$ which is a zero of $\sin (1/z)$

and $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin (1/z)} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{3! z^3} + \frac{1}{5! z^5} \cdots} = \frac{z}{ (1 -t)} $ , where $ t = \frac{1}{3! z^2} - \frac{1}{5! z^4} + \dots = z ( 1 + t + t^2 + \cdots   )$

Put the value of $t$  we get a Laurent series of $f$ and find that the coefficient of negative power $z$ are non zero. So $0$ is an essential singularity of $f$.

I am confused. Please tell me where I have made a mistake.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your geometric series converges for $|t|<1$ which is not satisfied on any neighbourhood of $z=0$.

In fact, $f$ doesn't have a Laurent series near $0$. Only functions that are holomorphic on annuli admit Laurent series, and there is no $r>0$ such that $f$ is holomorphic on $0<|z|<r$.

Comment: Thanks for editting, now it looks better.